# Can we copy part of Map as Image.?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Whenever I place a marker in Google Map using Google API. I want to copy the Map as Image near by the Marker.

**For example**:
Say I have placed a marker near "Hyderabad". I want capture the image of the Map with Marker.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is expressly forbidden by the Terms of Service.

You can use [Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to provide an image for you. There's even a [Static Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplewizard/makestaticmap.html) available to assist.

However, the Static Maps images need to be displayed with an `<img>` tag (so you can't embed them in an email).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are using it for. You should review the Google Maps API terms of service:
https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

You are not allowed to copy directly from the map, but you may be able to use the Static Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/